# portofino partnerapp for josso

Tags: josso

I want to make Portofino a partnerapp for josso, and i did the steps described here: http://www.manydesigns.com/documentation/tutorials/integration-with-josso.html, 
but I don't know how to connect josso with portofino because they use different servers.

Answer (score 0):

JOSSO has two parts: gateway and agent.

Gateway can be installed anywhere (and should be configured with a specific datastore), but agent should be installed on all servers that consume JOSSO authentication. JOSSO agent installs its hooks on web servers to control access.

So, you should install JOSSO agent on the web server instance that portofino runs on.